# Jira SOAPclient - dateTime fields

Tags: python, datetime, soap, jira

I'm using a python SOAPpy lib to connect to jira and create issues. It works quite well but I can't figure how to properly format the date (for the 'duedate' field) so Jira eats it.

The code for this is quite simple:

```
issue_params = dict()
issue_params['project'] = key
issue_params['type'] = str(issue_type)
issue_params['summary'] = title
issue_params['duedate'] = '{0}T00:00:00.000Z'.format(finish_plan.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
newissue = self.soap.createIssue(self.auth, issue_params)
```

for the issue_params['duedate'] I've tried so many different options (YYYY-MM-DD, ISO formats and what you see above, epoch, all sorts of things) but I keep getting the following error when I add the duedate attribute:

```
Fault soapenv:Server.userException: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch: 
SOAPpy.Types.structType detail at 75267848>: {'hostname': '*********', 'faultData': ''}>
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated the Python JIRA CLI plugin at https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/svn/JCLIMD/trunk/src
with how to do this for createIssue.

I would recommend using suds instead of SOAPpy, but this should work:

```
import SOAPpy.Types
issue_params['duedate'] = SOAPpy.Types.dateTimeType((int("2012"),
                                                        int("7"),
                                                        int("21"),
                                                        int(0),
                                                        int(0),
                                                        int(0),
                                                        ))
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this at work tomorrow. Oddly, I am able to update the issue and set its duedate (as yyyy/mm/dd string).

Comment: This solution does work in a weird way though - Jira will eat this but not set the duedate :)